# How to migrate SQL Server database to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database-migration

I have a **SQL Server** database with lots of data and an empty **MySQL** database. Now I want to copy all data of SQL Server database (including the database schema) to the MySQL database.

I thought about using raw SQL dump, but SQL Server's SQL syntax is not same as MySQL.

And I have googled some database migration tool, such as **south** (only for django), **simple-db-migration** (only for one type of database, maybe PostreSQL?) and **SQLAlchemy** (I haven't finished learning it, just feeling it somewhat clunky).

What tool can I use to do this migration?

Comment: you can use MySQL Workbench To migrate from MSSQL to MySQL

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm usually using [opendbcopy](http://opendbcopy.sourceforge.net/) for these kind of jobs ...

Comment: Is this still preferred? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I tried this tool once http://dbconvert.com/convert-mssql-to-mysql-pro.php , but you have to pay for the full version. Of course you can write your own migration script e.g. in PHP. On Windows it will be easy to connect to MSSQL server, from a Linux machine you have to use ODBC and that is sometimes a bit messy to install and configure.

Comment: I am too searching for this type of tool like i have database in Mysql or oracle or Excel and i want to take database from any of this sources and dump that database in my local sql server.can you please guide me a little about this tool?