# Migration from mssql to mysql

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to migrate MSSQL database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-mssql-database-to-mysql)

there is a asp.net 4.0 project that i'm working on, 
**database:Mssql**
i generated all the procedures , data access layers, and business layers using ignyter software, now i have a requirement that i am forced to convert the same project to mysql..

What are my options? 
are there any tools that convert all my tables and proedures to mysql,..
and also my business and data access layers..

Any opinions or options would be really great, i hate to redo all my work again..

Comment: You may have just learned a lesson on why you should think twice about putting too much application logic into a database. You now have your application tightly coupled with your data store.

Comment: There is nothing that is automated and will get things 100% correct. Some expressions in one SQL language variant just don't exist in others. As an aside, why MySQL? Why not something like PostgreSQL? (Does the person who made this decision realize that the MySQL client driver is GPL, and that this will likely "infect" your product, unless your company purchases a license?)

Comment: thanks brant.. what are my options now??

Comment: cdhowie .. thanks for your reply.. but we do have a licence.

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend for generating database script your MSSQL database and loading slowly fences in MYSQL.
To use MySQL with your project asp.Net uses this connector:
  [MYSQL CON](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

I used it and it has worked well.
I hope you work.

Comment: but how can i convert the tables and procedure in MSSQL to MYSQL?

Comment: utilizar Toad for MySQL para que ayude con el script
http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql/