# How do I export a single MSSQL table to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, import, export

I have a few tables with data from MSSQL 2008 r2 that I need to export to a file then import to MySQL. Exporting the whole database will take too much time because it's way big and I only need a select few of the tables.

The reason I indicated "single" on the title is because I plan on simply exporting the necessary tables one by one. So as to not complicate things. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-mssql-database-to-mysql).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I was facing a similar issue.

I solved it by creating a php script to select all the values from the MS SQL table and attach it onto the MYSQL db.
Once you have all the data you can even create a sql script file , i.e if MYSQL is not installed on the system.

There is also RedGate's excellent tools, which probably should give you whatever you want.
I myself have never used it but have heard about it.

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-toolbelt/

Answer (score -1):

You can do this from within SQL Server Management Studio by using the Export Import Wizard.

See [Export Import Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

In this case, you will use the SQL Server database table as the source, and the MySQL database table as the destination.

Comment: By the way, if you want to script this, the Export Import Wizard creates a SSIS package which can be saved and then run from SSIS. This, of course, is just one of many possible approaches.

Comment: There's no "database table" source and there's no MySQL database table as destination. :/