# Use sed/awk/grep to change order of a sentence

Tags: mysql, awk, sed

I'm trying to convert a MSSQL .sql file to MYSQL syntax file. I have managed to change some of the syntax using basic find/replace, but I also need to change the ordering of words in the line. Basically the statements are like this :

```
ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name)
```

and I want to correct the statements to this format(MYSQL syntax) :

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name(column_name)
```

There are like 70 statements of this sort in the file.Basically, table_name has to be shifted from between ON and (, and put in between TABLE and ADD. Is it possible to do this using sed/awk/grep?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-mssql-database-to-mysql ?

Comment: No I have tried migrating the files but there were too many errors and I feel changing the syntax is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following works in `sed` for your example input:

```
sed 's/\(ADD INDEX\) \(.*\) ON \(.*\)(/\3 \1 \2(/'
```

Comment: Thanks it worked like a charm :). I can't vote you up for now though.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this GNU sed command also,

```
sed -r 's/^(\w+\s\w+)(\s\w+\s\w+) (\w+) \w+ (\w+)(.*)$/\1 \4\2 \3\5/g' file
```

Example:

```
$ echo 'ALTER TABLE ADD INDEX index_name ON table_name(column_name)' | sed -r 's/^(\w+\s\w+)(\s\w+\s\w+) (\w+) \w+ (\w+)(.*)$/\1 \4\2 \3\5/'
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD INDEX index_name(column_name)
```