# Replicating MSSQL Database to MySQl Through MSSQL Replication

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, backup

**It is a possible of duplicate question may be** but please suggest me some work around

I got this requirement.

I have a MSSQL Database with almost 30 Tables with millions of records.
Now i need to take Replica of the same in MySql.

The Solution which i am thinking are (This may contains loopholes and it may not be good)

**Sol 1 :-** 
   I created a linked server of MySql and by using trigger in MSSQL Tables and insert in MySQl
For the existing records by using import wizard of workbench import the data.

**Sol 2 :-**
   Using [SymmetricDS.](http://www.symmetricds.org)

What is the best way to achieve this.

I am very new to Database Administration stuffs. Please help me in this regard.

**Note :-** After we replicated to MySql it should be in sync with MSSQL.

**UPDATE :-**
    If anyone knows as the way `dan b` said how to do it via SQL Server Replication Using ODBC please 
give some reference.

I tried this steps [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/how-do-i/how-do-i-set-up-replication-between-microsoft-sql-server-2000-and-mysql/). In the second step if i click new publication under Replication SSMS i got this error

```
SQL Server replication requires the actual server name to make a 
connection to the server. 
Connections through a server alias, IP address, or any other 
alternative name are not suppported. Specify the actual server name, 
'USER3-PC'. (Replication.Utilities)
```

I installed SQL 2008 R2 Express. And this i tried in my local machine.

Comment: They have to be kept in sync afterwards?  Which one will be considered correct if both db's are written to?

Comment: We are writing only to MSSQL. But we should find a way it should update that record in mysql also

Comment: [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-mssql-database-to-mysql)

Comment: @csaw Thanks for for ur reply. I referred that link..
That is to copy the data but i need MySql to be in Sync with MSSQL.

Comment: There are other questions asking exactly that, however, most point to using other libraries. There is I believe a way to do it using MSSQL data replication and setting up mysql as an ODBC data source.   Check all the relevant stackexchange answers. I don't see it there. You could then modify your question asking specifically if it can be done using MS SQL replication

Answer (score 0):

I would just create PHP scripts to do it.  I would create on script per table and run them from the command line.  There are drivers for both MSSQL and MySQL.  Since PHP is loosely typed this should be a breeze.  You can get the create and insert statements right from SQL Server Management Studio.