# How can I migrate my MsSQL database on a hosted website to a MySQL database on a different hosted website?

Tags: mysql, database, sql-server-2008

I have a MsSQL 2008 database hosted on somee.com . I have purchased another hosting under net4.in which is providing me MySQL database. So now, how can I migrate/synchronise my MsSQL database to the MySQL database ?

I have tried below things but in vain :

1. There is an inbuilt facility provided in the MySQL in net4.in to synchronise two databases on remote servers,where I have tried selecting the target server as "Current Server" and in Source Server, I have selected "Remote Server" and provided connection details which were available to me from somee.com . Unfortunately, the Socket and Port details are not provided on somee.com, I have tried giving various values like "TCP/IP" and "1433"(the default value) but in vain.
2. There is an import facility in MySQL in net4.in , in which I have given the format of imported file as "SQL" and SQL compatibility mode as "MSSQL" , but it is giving an error showing some encrypted text from my MSSQL database saying that its not able to understand it.

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3153/need-to-migrate-sql-server-to-mysql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-mssql-database-to-mysql

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to export SQL Server database to MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3917081/how-to-export-sql-server-database-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to export a csv or .sql file of your existing database then import it using our web-based DB management tools at http://db.infuseweb.com.
However, this may not always be effective especially if you have very large database files.  In which case you will need to submit a support ticket and provide us with a MSSQL .bak file or all the MySQL database files from your old host. You will also need to create an empty database in Helm with the exact same database name and users/passwords that you have with your old host. We will then move the database under your account.