# SQL database -> MySQL database conversion

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm working on a C# WinForms app that's currently connected to a SQL Server db, and will eventually create a mobile app through Xamarin.

Is it possible to utilize my existing SQL db, or will I have to create a MySQL db file from scratch? I'm not very familiar with MySQL, but I know it's possible to import/export SQL db's from/to various other formats.

Comment: possible duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-sql-server-database-to-mysql?

Comment: I'll give this a go, thanks!

Comment: no worries, good luck!