# PHP script to backup MS SQL database

Tags: php, sql-server

Task is simple: I want to export all MS SQL database tables from SQL Management Studio 2008 R2 to MYSQL (or any other format that MySQL can take, e.g Excel, CSV, etc.).

I have tried the following:

MySQL Workbench - Successful in creating everything but did not copy the data for **some** tables
Import/Export wizard in SQL Server Management Studio. This fails for all cases (of various destination options) with a useful error message when exporting to excel (see below).

While Googling my way around this, the data export is failing due to invalid length of data that have some encoding. My guess is that a certain type of encoding that is not suppose to be more than 4000 bytes is having data stored more than 4000 bytes.

I confirmed this while attempting to export to excel. It showed the following error:

> Error 0xc0204016: SSIS.Pipeline: The "output column "Subject" (83)"
>   has a length that is not valid. The length must be between 0 and 4000.
>        (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> ```
> Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204016 (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap)
> ```

The above error shows is on some of the tables, this is evident in the fact that MySQL Workbench actually exported data for tables that are not affected, and then simply created tables for those affected (without exporting data to them)

I need help with how to backup this database. The solution that pops up in my head is that of [David Walsh](https://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php) but the solution backsup MySQL database. Is there a way to do the same on this Myssql database? (using php script)

Note that this is not a duplicate because the problem of encoding that I mentioned nullifies the solutions proffered by other SO answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to migrate SQL Server database to MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-sql-server-database-to-mysql)

Comment: It is not a duplicate because the problem of encoding that I mentioned nullifies the solutions proffered in the link