# Link and export data from Azure SQL table to my SQL table

Tags: mysql, azure, azure-sql-database

Is there any possibility to export and create a link between one of the table from Azure SQL DB to the table in  MySQL DB?

Comment: Does "my SQL" DB mean MySQL db? Or just your db? (Big difference.)

Comment: It is MySQL db.

Comment: Do you want to copy data from Azure SQL database  to on-premise MySQL DB?

Comment: Yes.and any changes in Azure SQL table should be reflected in MYSQL DB table always.

Comment: I would go back to the drawing board and review this architecture.If what you need is daily backups and a db where you can have those backups running (kind of copy of production for dev environment), you can automate this in many different ways.

Comment: Hi Prathyusha Dwibhashi, you can use  MySQL Workbench Migration , Amazon DMS or Data Integration (Kettle). please see my update.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you can migrate data from SQL server to your MySQL database. And there are many ways can help you achieve that. You can reference this blog :[How to migrate SQL Server database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-sql-server-database-to-mysql).

But for Azure, you could not copy or migrate data from Azure SQL database to your on-premise MySQL DB, even with [Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-mysql). Azure Data Factory only support MySQL as source server.

Secondly, You want to sync the data between Azure SQL database and your MySQL database. [Azure SQL Data Sync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-sync-data) only support Azure SQL Database and on-premise SQL Server instance.

This means that Azure could not help you migrate or sync data from Azure SQL data base to MySQL DB. You have to use third-party tools.

**One of the ways is you can use  [MySQL Workbench Migration](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/migrate/) tool**. Database migrations - enables migrations from Microsoft SQL Server, Microsoft Access, PostgreSQL, Sybase ASE, Sybase SQL Anywhere, SQLite, and more.

There are many tools to perform the migration from MS SQL Server to MySQL like **Amazon DMS** or [Data Integration (Kettle)](https://community.hitachivantara.com/docs/DOC-1009855), but in this case, we’ll use the MySQL Workbench Migration tool.

Please reference this tutorial: [How to Migrate from MSSQL to MySQL](https://severalnines.com/blog/how-migrate-mssql-mysql).

Hope this helps.