# How to set up a server to run an application which is based on PHP language

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, dts

We have real old server running DTS packages and SSMS 2008 or older. We need to transfer our DB to new server that can also run PHP applications.
What do I need to do to set it up?

Thank you,

Comment: (1) Is it true that you already have a system in place (written in PHP) accessing the data in the MS SQL server ?  (2) If not, what are the reason(s) that you want to migrate the DB to one which can run PHP ?

Comment: It's an old server vulnerable to hacking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using an old Win server that is vulnerable to hacking and wish to replace it with a new one (capable of running PHP), broadly you have two choices:

**Windows Server**

a) You may stick to using Win server OS and upgrade the db version and server OS to the latest version (SQL Server 2022 and Win Server: 2022) , then if you wish to run PHP on the machine, you may install it thru Microsoft Web Platform Installer so that the machine will be one with IIS capable of running PHP. For details, please refer to MS site:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-and-configure-php

**Linux Server**

b) you may choose to set up a linux server which is capable of running PHP/MySQL, and migrate the existing MSSQL database (as you have specifically mentioned) to MySQL thru some sort of migration tools

For setting up a linux server capable of running PHP (aka LAMP), you may refer to the following link (and others)

https://superuser.com/questions/993316/how-do-i-set-up-a-lamp-server-from-scratch-using-centos-6-7

For migrating the MSSQL to MySQL, you may refer to this SO post for some reference / information:

[How to migrate SQL Server database to MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019144/how-to-migrate-sql-server-database-to-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

1. I prefer Ubuntu for a long time, so I would install the latest Ubuntu version on a server.
2. I would use apt install to install mysql and php8.
3. Dump the old database to file and copy it to new server.
4. Import the new database.